# Long rest regains half hit dice - round up or down?

Tags: dnd-5e

When having a long rest, you regain all your hit points and *half* your spent Hit Dice (for use in future short rests). I know that normally when faced with fractions you round down. But then, I see no way to regain your 1 Hit Die at 1st level.

So basic question: if you are at first level, and you take a long rest, do you regain your Hit Die, or do you not because you had to halve 1 and round down?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The general rule is to round down, so you round down.

Unless you are told otherwise in the rules, D&D always mandates you round down. The Long rest section has no such exception (the only exception I've seen so far is for the wizard's spell recovery)

v.2 of BD&D now includes language that indicates a minimum of 1 HD is recovered during a long rest.

> The character also regains spent Hit Dice, up to a number of dice equal to half of the character’s total number of them (minimum of one die). (p 67)

Comment: Basic v0.2 does now say the minimum is 1 HD (p. 67).

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately the answer is quite simple. From the Basic Rules (still applies in PHB):

> **Round Down** There's one more general rule you need to know at the outset. Whenever you divide a number in the game, round down if you
>   end up with a fraction, even if the fraction is one-half or greater.
>   *~ Basic Rules, p. 4*

This should apply in all cases, *except* where it logically should not. The case you mention here would be a good example. Remember that it is very hard to make RAW consistent and synchronized at all times when it spans hundreds of pages. A bit of interpretation is often necessary.